# Encoding problem when sending a request using RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Sending a request using RestTemplate

```java
    var emailDto = new EmailDto();
    email.setBody(DATA_TEXT);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text", "html", utf8);
    headers.setContentType(mediaType);
    var httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(emailDto , headers);
    //restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
    //   .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    var response = restTemplate.exchange(
    ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.exchange(
            emailPath,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            httpEntity,
            String.class);
```

DATA_TEXT - here is a piece of html code that I'm trying to send in a request

```java
    public static final String DATA_TEXT = "<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'> " +
    "<table role='table' style='width:100%%;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;background:#ffffff;'> " +
"<tr> <td align='center' style='padding:0;'> " +
"<table role='table' style='width:602px;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #cccccc;border-spacing:0;text-align:left;'> " +
"<tr> <td align='center' style='padding:4px 0 4px;background:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #cccccc;'> " +
"<img src='https://i.logo.co/redfggq7/logo.png' alt='my_logo' width='170' " +
"</td></tr><tr> <td style='padding:36px 30px 42px 30px;background:#F0F4F2;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;'> " +
"<p style='font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;'>Текст авпвапва вар о пор ораоа про прп" +
"</p><p style='font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;'>" +
"</p>" +
"</td></tr><tr> <td style='padding:30px;background:#198754;text-align:center;border:1px solid #cccccc;'> " +
"<a style='text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;opacity:50%%' href='#'>my.com</a> " +
"</td></tr></table></td></tr></table> </body>";
```

When sending a request, it returns the following error:
`org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for ru.ocpiouserbacktest.model.EmailDto and content type "text/html;charset=UTF-8"`

In the file Pom.xml specified

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text", "html", utf8);
headers.setContentType(mediaType);
```

You're telling Spring that the content of your payload will be text/html.

However, with this:

```
var httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(emailDto , headers);
```

You're telling Spring to send an EmailDto object - which understandably  Spring has no idea how to convert to text/html and Spring won't know that EmailDto happens to contain a field with HTML in it.